# How can i foreach all buttons in winforms (many groupboxes)

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 6 buttons in three groupboxes (groupbox1, etc). All is in form1
And i try to enabled all.. but nothing is happening

```
foreach(var cmd in  this.Controls.OfType<Button>())
{
    cmd.Enabled = true;
}
```

This is the correct solution ?

```
foreach(var gb in this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>())
{
    foreach (var cmd in gb.Controls.OfType<Button>())
    {
       cmd.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If the buttons are within other controls, then you need to recurse the control collection until you find them.

Comment: i added the solution, is it ok ?

Comment: Looks fine, what happens when you try it?

Comment: it works ;) but bellow Adrian gave diffrend code which it works too.
Which is better ?

Comment: The solutions are essentially identical. Go with the one you understand better.

Comment: My solution i understand ;) but i would like understand Adrian solutions too ;)
Any way thx for help.

Comment: Adrian's solution would offer better readability had you many nested foreaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to access the `Controls` properties within each `GroupBox` in order to get the desired `Button` instances.

Your proposed solution does work, but you could use LINQ's `SelectMany` linke this instead:

```
foreach (var button in Controls.OfType<GroupBox>()
      .SelectMany(groupBox => groupBox.Controls.OfType<Button>()))
{
    button.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: it works ;) what is better solution ? My or yours ?